# Swift custom UITableView not showing up in build

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm having a problem in which my custom `UITableView` will not show up when I build my application.

Currently, I've built what the custom table should look like in my storyboard and also have created a cocoa class that is linked to the `UITableViewCell`.

This is the ViewController code that deals with retrieving the input form an array and then pasting it onto the table

```
import UIKit

struct eventStruct
{
    let eventHost : String
    let eventStatus : String
    let eventPrice : String
}

class eventsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var eventArrayData = [eventStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        eventArrayData = [eventStruct(eventHost: "Event1", eventStatus: "OPEN", eventPrice: "$5"),
                              eventStruct(eventHost: "Event2", eventStatus: "CLOSED", eventPrice: "$0")]
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return (eventArrayData.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let eventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventTemplate", for: indexPath) as! eventsTableViewCell

        eventCell.eventHost.text = eventArrayData[indexPath.row].eventHost
        eventCell.eventPrice.text = eventArrayData[indexPath.row].eventPrice
        eventCell.eventStatus.text = eventArrayData[indexPath.row].eventStatus

        return (eventCell)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Any extra information that is needed and/or help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try add `self.tableView.reloadData()` at the end of the function `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: I don't see you implementing `numberOfSections` data source method. Make sure it returns more than 0. Also capitalize your `EventsViewController`, it's not a requirement but a good coding convention.

Comment: @YunCHEN If I add that line of code, it throws a "ambiguous reference to member"

Comment: And where is your tableView `var` declared and its dataSource property assigned? Are you creating them in interface builder?

Comment: Have you connected delegate and datasouce to the viewcontroller?

Comment: I dont see the delegate for setting the tableview cell height. Consider adding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not connected delegate to your view controller

you can connect your delegate in two ways

1) Using `viewDidLoad()` function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      yourTableVeiw.delegate = self
      yourTableView.dataSource = self
}
```

2) Using `storyboard`

just drag and drop on your view controller

follow below image

[image]

Comment: And how do you know that he has not connected it in IB? :)